# re.sub with back-references

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do something in `python` with `re.sub` similar to the way one would do so with sed in bash.  I am having trouble back-referencing the groups which I read was done with `\g<>` but it seems I am doing it wrong.

I want to eliminate space within a set of delimiters or a delimiter and the beginning/end of the line:

```
line1 = 'blah < b la a ah > blah'
line2 = ' b la a ah > blah'
line3 = 'blah < b la a ah '

line1 = re.sub(r"< (.*) (.*) >", r"< \g<1>\g<2> >", line1)
line2 = re.sub(r"^ (.*) (.*) >", r" \g<1>\g<2> >", line2)
line3 = re.sub(r"< (.*) (.*) $", r"< \g<1>\g<2> ", line3)
```

If this were bash I would do something like:

```
sed 's/< \(.*\) \(.*\) >/< \1\2 >/g' | sed 's/< \(.*\) \(.*\) $/< \1\2 /g' | sed 's/^ \(.*\) \(.*\) >/ \1\2 >/g'
```

Comment: What about just [`line = re.sub(r"\s*(?=[^<>]*>)", "", line)`](https://ideone.com/XtX052)?

Comment: that looks perfect!  I guess I was trying to split things up for clarity but doing it all in one go is even better.

Comment: @stribizhev this should be the solution I believe

Comment: I posted it with a bit of explanation. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I would still be interested to know why my back-references didn't work

Comment: They work, the 2nd and third regexes do not match the input. I can update the answer.

Comment: @stribizhev are you sure they work? For me in ipython, even the first doesn't match...

Comment: Have another closer look at [your code](https://ideone.com/jGBQHu) demo: the first one works well, `a ah` is replaced with `aah`.

Comment: The [updated code demo](https://ideone.com/j34bmr) proves the back-references work alright. Note that `.*` is greedy, it matches as many characters as possible to accommodate for a match, that is why you get such "interesting" results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at [your code demo](https://ideone.com/jGBQHu): `'blah < b la a ah > blah'` is turned into `blah < b la aah > blah` with the first `re.sub`, but later, none of the 2 final regexes match the modified string.

The [`^ (.*) (.*) >` (second) regex](https://regex101.com/r/aO7mH5/1) expects a space at the beginning, and there is none. The [third regex `< (.*) (.*) $`](https://regex101.com/r/aO7mH5/2) expects a final space - and there is none.

You can use a one-regex solution. The regex - `r"\s*(?=[^<>]*>)"` - will match any whitespace, 0 or more occurrences (`\s*`), that is followed by any number of any characters but a `<` or `>` up to the first `>` (with the `(?=[^<>]*>)` look-ahead).

```
line = re.sub(r"\s*(?=[^<>]*>)", "", line)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XtX052)

Result: `blah <blaaah> blah`

Note that the [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) does not consume the characters, that is why we only remove whitespace (that is matched) with this regex.

Comment: you are assuming that I want to continue matching the same line.  My three expressions are actually for different contexts.  Still the solution does work.

Comment: :) What else can I assume when looking at your code? :)

Comment: fair enough, I could have given the other contexts.  I will update

Comment: I hope I made this more clear, but if not feel free to make changes.  I am still a newbie.

Comment: I am not sure what you want(ed) to obtain in each case. I just want to warn you that your regex is poorly written. You must have heard of backtracking: if a regex contains `+`, `*`, `?`, `{1}` or `|`, it will backtrack, check preceding subpatterns if the quantified one fails. In your regex, `.` matches a space, too, thus your `< (.*) (.*) >` takes a lot of resources to find or fail a match. As in Python we have no variable-width lookbehind, nor `\G` operator, we cannot check left/right context within one regex. My solution is a workaround assuming the brackets are paired OK. Else, it'll fail.